# Git config with condifional does not work with url rewrites

Tags: git, go, github, git-config, go-get

I have two different work folders in my computer one is in ~/Documents/work/companyA other is in ~/work/companyB. I wrote conditional gitconfig that is like

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/work/companyA/"]
    path = ~/Documents/work/companyA/.gitconfig

[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/work/companyB/"]
    path = ~/Documents/work/companyB/.gitconfig
```

and the content of both of these files are like

```
[user]
        name = companyAuser
        email = user@companyA.com

[url "ssh://git@github-companyA/"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

I know this file is being read and git@github-companyA is valid because when I run

```
git config user.email
ssh -T git@github-companyA
```

in a directory inside ~/Documents/work/companyA/ both of these commands work correctly.

i am using this config to "go get" from a private repository. Also when i put the URL rewrite command to ~/.gitconfig it works correct. How can i fix this

Comment: any chance that configuration setting could be overridden by another one ? one way to debug your config: `git config --show-origin --list`

Comment: Hi thanks for the recommendation i just checked and there is no override

Comment: ok, and do you see the settings you expect ? (listed from `companyA/.gitconfig` or `companyB/.gitconfig` depending on the working directory when you run `git config --list`)

Comment: Yes i see all the settings in companyA/.gitconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misread your question: it is not a git question, it is actually a "go get + git" question.

The locations used by `go get` are located under the `GOMODCACHE` directory, not under your working directory.

Here is an illustration using `strace` on a `go get github.com/spf13/cast` command (I simulated a private repo by setting `GOPRIVATE=github.com/spf13/cast`) :

```
...
[pid 711376] chdir("/home/LeGEC/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/60c669232b830322cfc3d9e570d86c2297d36fdbc38de8ad322b59a3dff47a24") = 0
[pid 711376] execve("/usr/bin/git", ["git", "init", "--bare"], 0xc00046a000 /* 94 vars */) = 0
...
[pid 711377] execve("/usr/bin/git", ["git", "remote", "add", "origin", "--", "https://github.com/spf13/cast"], 0xc00046a300 /* 94 vars */) = 0
...
```

---

Possible workarounds:

- if your can target more specific urls (for example: `github.com/companyA/` instead of all of `github.com/`), you can set replacement urls globally, e.g:

```ini
# in your ~/.gitconfig:
[url "ssh://git@github-companyA/companyA/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/companyA/
```

- use one of the [environment variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#ENVIRONMENT) to specify a gitconfig file, for the duration of one of your `go get` commands; for example:

```bash
GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=~/Documents/work/companyA/.gitconfig  go get ...
```

- set `GOMODCACHE` to a location under `~/Documents/work/companyA/` when you work on a repo for `companyA`
  *note*: this would lead to having several copies of your go cache on your disk

Comment: Thanks a lot, I decided to go with the first workaround you recommended